# Android: Textview scrolling issue on orientation change

Tags: android, scroll, textview, orientation

In my app i want to show facebook updates. I used a textview to do the same with marquee limit 2. The problem is when the orientation changes the text starts scroll from the beginning. How can i fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in ur android manifest(in the activity) so that the orientation changes wont affect ur activity.
    `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"`

Comment: @Unnikrishnan: Just check whether ur activity is creating again when the `orientation` is changed. If it is recreating tat can be avoided by this code. Check tat thing.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan: In that case change the `textView` to `EditText` cos i came across this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255777/scrolling-textview-repaint-problem. in which the comment stated this.